# How to calculate the gain of the op amp in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, ldr

[image]

This op amp operates as a difference amplifier and VR2 is for feedback, But I can't figure out how to calculate the gain of this circuit, Any ideas?

Comment: VR2 is NOT for negative feedback, since it returns to the positive input it is positive feedback. So it's a comparator with hysteresis, gain is a meaningless term. The only rational figure you could put on the gain is infinity, and even that's a fiction.

Comment: In this circuit, opamp acts as a comparator. The reference voltage is Vcc/2. LDR has a dark resistance of >20k so in dark areas, negative input of comparator will be >Vcc/2 and comparator's output will be LOW, transistor gets cut off and deactivates the relay. If light comes to LDR then its resistance will decrease. Then comparator's output will be HIGH and relay will be activated. VR2 is for hysteresis. Not for negative feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an amplifier but a Schmitt trigger, because the feedback resistor VR2 is between the output and the positive input.

So as soon the output becomes positive, the positive input becomes more positive and following, the output becomes even more positive.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger#Op-amp_implementations